# EventFlow registration in .net core 3.1 API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have package references to EventFlow and EventFlow.AspNetCore. But can't register service:

```
 services.AddEventFlow(ef =>
            {
                ef.AddDefaults(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
                ef.AddAspNetCoreMetadataProviders();
            });
```

Receiving an error:

```
CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddEventFlow' and no accessible extension method 'AddEventFlow' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Usings as follows:

```
using EventFlow.AspNetCore.Extensions;
using EventFlow.AspNetCore.Configuration;
using EventFlow;
using EventFlow.Extensions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. You need to add EventFlow.DependencyInjection package to your project. AddEventFlow method is defined there.